Не выводит реверс строки на русском dev c++
Нужно перевернуть слово САМОДОСТАТОЧНОСТЬ и вывести на экран. При выполнении программы на нужном месте пусто. Но если строка будет состоять из латиницы, то всё отображается верно.
Пробовал менять кодировки, использовать reverse().
Версия Embarcadero Dev-C++ 6.3
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    char s[] = "САМОДОСТАТОЧНОСТЬ", s1[20];
    cout<<s<<endl;
    strcpy(s1,s); strrev(s1);
    cout<<s1<<endl;
}


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Это же кодировка utf-8. Дело в том, что в ней ascii (7-bit) символы занимают в памяти 1 байт, а кириллица 2. При тривиальном переворачивании в русских символах первый и второй байт будут меняться местами. Да и 20 байт для s1 в вашем примере недостаточно. Тут нужно минимум 35

@Духсообщества что-то кто-то часто из проверок прикрывается ботом. Не понятно зачем, с вопросом все нормально.
